# Fullcalendar compatibility with chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, frontend

I've got problem with FullCalendar. On Firefox, everything works fine, but on IE, or Chrome, every cells aren't on the properly places, and are too low. Here is a screen. Any ideas?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please, porovide more information(HTML, CSS, Jquery, jsfiddle and etc).

Comment: Ok, here is the code, from this view: http://pastebin.com/PWzLpJKn
I'm using Jquery 2.1.1 and ASP.NET MVC 5

Comment: Please, add a demo which works.

Comment: Here: http://imgur.com/IveqiiQ

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot figure out your problem by image.

Comment: alireza safian: so, what can I do for you?

Comment: I need to see your live demo that I understand your problem.

Comment: Live demo means movie?

Comment: I can interact with it. Go to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and paste your code in suitable frame.